# Traveling salesman problem

Tags: decision-problem

Could someone tell me how many stopping points are needed for the traveling salesman to be impractical to be solved by current computing?

Comment: "The current TSP state-of-the-art exact solver, Concorde, remains unbeaten. Concorde has been used to optimally solve instances of several thousand cities and, for fewer than 1 000 cities, does so in very feasible running times." [source](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-16711-0_7.pdf)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the hardness of a TSP instance is *not* measured by the number of cities. Small instances can be considerably more difficult than huge instances. The same is true for any NP-hard problem. Further, an instance can be rather easy for algorithm A but a lot harder for algorithm B. The opposite can be true for some other instance.